# Vhost Zend Framework configuration MAMP - redirected to the index page of the server

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have checked out the posts and made the appropriate changes to the configuration files to make zend framework 2 to work on my local environment. Everything goes fine but the redirection of the page on specifying the vhost name doesnot work appropriately. It displays me the home page of the MAMP server with the directory listing.
Here is what I have done till now:

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newportalcopper.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NewPortalCopper/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NewPortalCopper/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   newportalcopper.localhost localhost
```

Can some one tell me what i am doing wrong that this particular thing is not working.

Comment: Have you enabled the site's vhost? You probably have a "sites-available" and "sites-enabled" directory and you must create a symlink from the availables to the enabled.

Comment: need to check that out dont have any knowledge regarding the same... Can you please provide a reference how to check this out

Comment: @JurianSluiman Moreover I am using MAMP as the server on my mac... so I am not able to find the folders into the installation

Comment: Did you restart the apache service? :-)

Comment: Try `<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NewPortalCopper/public">` instead of `<Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NewPortalCopper/public>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for viewing the post guys and the help specified. At the end i was able to sort the problem out.
The main issue was the port number in case of MAMP. It was required to be 8888 instead of 80. This specifically solved my problem.