# Zend Framework 2, vhosts and MAMP

Tags: apache, zend-framework2, mamp, vhosts

I think I've configured all files properly, but when I access the url: myapp.local, it points to the MAMP/htdocs/ directory instead of /MAMP/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public/ (going to this public directory displays correctly de zf2 example webpage), here is my configuration:

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName myapp.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public/"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public/">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.local
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I want my base url to point at the /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public/ directory, not at htdocs.

Similar question here, but I can't get the answer. [Vhost Zend Framework configuration MAMP - redirected to the index page of the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715770/vhost-zend-framework-configuration-mamp-redirected-to-the-index-page-of-the-se)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this in the `httpd.conf` file (where you must have enabled to include the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file) -

```
<VirtualHost myapp.local>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication-master/public/"
</VirtualHost>
```

There should be no need to enable the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Comment: i just had to uncomment 
`Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`